# JavaScript click div to show hidden content animation

Tags: javascript, css

I am working on this JavaScript animated accordion, trying to get it to where when a Section div is clicked, a hidden panel slides down from behind it to reveal hidden content. Then when the bar is clicked again, the hidden area slides back up and becomes hidden again. This is almost working the way I need it to apart from a couple of issues that I haven't been able to solve.

1. The vertical distance between the section bars should remain
   consistent before and after the hidden area is revealed or hidden.
   Right now, there is an undesired margin between them.
2. When the hidden area slides back up to be hidden again, it needs to
   slide all the way up so that the border of the hidden area also
   disappears.

I believe there are a couple of small changes to my JavaScript/css code that could enable this to work properly, I just haven't been able to find them.

Here is what my code looks like:

```js
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("bar");
var i;

// For each bar
for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {

  // If this bar is clicked
  acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    
    // Toggle the clicked bar to "active"
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    
    // Panel will consist of the next hidden content
    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
    var bar = this.nextElementSibling.nextElementSibling;
    console.log("hidden height:", panel.getBoundingClientRect().height)
    
    // Use logic to change CSS styles for the selected bar
    if (panel.style.maxHeight){
      
      var closeHeight = panel.getBoundingClientRect().height;
      console.log("close height", closeHeight)
      var newHeight = (closeHeight - 80) + "px";
      panel.style.height = newHeight
      console.log("close height after adjustment", newHeight)
      
      // panel.style.border = 'none';
      panel.style.maxHeight = null;
      console.log("close maxheight", panel.style.maxHeight)
      
      // panel.style.maxHeight = '0px';
      
      // panel.style.padding = '0 18px';
      panel.style.paddingTop = '80px';
      panel.style.border = 'solid 1px #aaa';
      
      bar.style.marginTop = '-15px'
      // panel.style.border = 'none';
      
      
    } else {
      // bar.style.marginTop = '15px'
      panel.style.border = 'solid 1px #aaa';
      panel.style.paddingTop = '80px';
      panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
      console.log("open maxheight", panel.style.maxHeight)
      console.log("open height", panel.getBoundingClientRect().height)
    } 
  });
}
```

```css
.bar {
  width: 350px;
  height: 90px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 24px;
  margin: 70px 15px 15px 15px;
/*   margin: 15px 15px 15px 15px; */
  z-index: -2;
  background-color: #eee;
  color: #444;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px solid #444;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 16px;
/*   transition: 0.4s; */
  transition: 3.4s;
}

.active, .bar:hover {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.hidden {
  width: 340px;
/*   height: 370px; */
/*   border: solid 1px #aaa; */
  border-radius: 8px;
  margin: -80px 0px 15px 0px;
  padding: 0 18px;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
/*   transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out; */
  transition: max-height 3.2s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<button class="bar">Section 1</button>
<div class="hidden">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>

<button class="bar">Section 2</button>
<div class="hidden">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor 
    incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud 
    exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
  
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor 
    incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud 
    exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
  
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor 
    incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud 
    exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>

<button class="bar">Section 3</button>
<div class="hidden">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>
```

This is also visible on codepen:
https://codepen.io/Chris_Nielsen/pen/Lozedd

Comment: is there a reason you don't want to use jQuery for this?

Comment: I would rather use jQuery, and I tried converting it to jQuery, but failed to find the equivalent jQuery code.

Comment: if you're ok with using jQuery, I'd recommend using this effect https://jqueryui.com/accordion/

Comment: That example doesn't function they way I need it to, also I don't have access to jQuery UI.

Comment: did you look through all the examples from the right side menu? if you need it to collapse, there's an option for that. Also, what do you mean you don't have access to jQuery UI? You can't include the CDN link?

Comment: My target environment includes jQuery CDN, but not jQuery UI CDN, and I can't add jQuery UI.

Comment: Script links don't need to be in the head, but that's beside the point. jQuery accordions are easy-peasy even without UI. Let us know which way you want to go. Also, I wouldn't do styling in your script. Use CSS classes and descendant selectors.

Comment: I have created this kind of functionality before using jQuery. See:
https://codepen.io/Chris_Nielsen/pen/MVMbvP
However, this case is unique in that the hidden content needs to start and end partially behind the bar.

Comment: The code I have above is almost complete. It just needs a couple of small tweaks I suspect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because CSS + javascript is so powerful nowadays, the need of JQuery is unnecessary.

- I removed lots of javascript code.
- I added `.information` as a class to all `.hidden` divs.
- I added an extra div inside the `.hidden.information` div. I'm using this to calculate the real height of the hidden text blocks.
- I finally added a CSS variable so you only need to change the displacement of the `.hidden.information` text blocks in one place.

```js
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("bar");
var i

// For each bar
for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  // If this bar is clicked
  acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    // Toggle the clicked bar to "active"
    this.classList.toggle("active");        

    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;

    if (!panel.style.maxHeight) {  // add only once
     var elementDisplacement = getComputedStyle(panel).getPropertyValue("--element-displacement");
     elementDisplacement = Number( elementDisplacement.replace("px", "") );

     var panelChildHeight = panel.firstElementChild.getBoundingClientRect().height;
     panel.style.maxHeight = panelChildHeight + elementDisplacement + "px";
    }

    panel.classList.toggle("hidden");
  });

}
```

```css
.bar {
  width: 350px;
  height: 90px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 24px;
  margin: 70px 15px 15px 15px;
  z-index: -2;
  background-color: #eee;
  color: #444;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px solid #444;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 16px;

}

.active, .bar:hover {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.information {
  --element-displacement: 80px;

  width: 340px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  margin: calc(-1 * var(--element-displacement)) 0px 15px 0px;
  padding: 0 18px;
  padding-top: var(--element-displacement);
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  max-height: initial;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 1s ease-out;
}

.hidden {
  max-height: 0px !important;
  border-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<button class="bar">Section 1</button>
<div class="hidden information">
 <div>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
 </div>
</div>

<button class="bar">Section 2</button>
<div class="hidden information">
 <div>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor 
    incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud 
    exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
  
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor 
    incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud 
    exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
  
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor 
    incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud 
    exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
 </div>
</div>

<button class="bar">Section 3</button>
<div class="hidden information">
 <div>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Holy crap that is clever! Works perfectly too. Thanks!
https://codepen.io/Chris_Nielsen/pen/rgYJKd

Comment: I noticed that the border disappears right away, but the text slides up. Is there a way to make the border stay visible and slide up with the content and disappear only after it reaches the top?

Comment: You can achieve that in javascript, but a common trick is otherwise to change opacity, through CSS, on the whole element and fade it out after a certain amount of time. Lets say 200ms before the max-height animation ends.

Comment: I have converted most of this to jQuery, except I am having trouble converting this part to a jQuery equivalent:
`getBoundingClientRect().height;`